# Image comparison approach

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to compare an image of a past state of an object with one taken recently

for example

i have this image of that object last year and i have a recent picture i need to detect the differences between those images and put an overlay over the new picture.
can anyone guide me how to approach this any further?

here is an example picture: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVsU0.png)

I've tried to add a gaussian blur but i have stalled ever since.
thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cv2.absdiff(frame1,frame2) to compare the difference between two frames.

Once you find the areas of difference that are above a certain threshold, you can use cv2.rectangle() to draw the rectangle around it.

Below is an example of cv2.absdiff() for motion detection. You can probably repurpose the code to what you're trying to do:

https://github.com/methylDragon/opencv-motion-detector/blob/master/Motion%20Detector.py